# Using cmakesettings.json with cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am novice at cmake, so please be gentle.

I have a medium sized project that has been using visual studio with cmake. I would like to use the build/install features that I currently use in visual studio, but with cmake in the terminal.

Currently the project uses a cmakesettings.json to switch between the different builds and locations. When I searched this though, it seems to be specific to visual studio?

https://github.com/microsoft/CmakeSettings

Is there a tool or easy way to use these settings with cmake instead of visual studio?

Comment: CMakeSettings is superseded by [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html), use them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in VS2019, the correct way to do this is to use CMakePresets.json and then you can build in a VS2019 or higher, VS2022, or in a CI using cmake from the cmd.exe. CMakeSettings.json is deprecated. To enabled support for them, there is an option that needs to be enabled. See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-160 for more information.